# show json with jstree 3.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jstree

I've been trying to load a json file from apache, and show it's result with jstree, 3.0.0.
Here is my code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#showTree').jstree({
       'core' : {
               'data' : { 
                         'url' : function (node) {
                                 return node= 'miley.json';
                                 },
                     'data' : function (node) {
                                 return { 'id' : node.id };
                                                  }
                        }
                }
                         });
        });
```

Know miley:

```
[
   { "id" : "ajson1", "parent" : "national", "text" : "Simple root node" },
   { "id" : "ajson2", "parent" : "le", "text" : "Root node 2" },
   { "id" : "ajson3", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Child 1" },
   { "id" : "ajson4", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Child 2" },
]
```

My console swears it receives the json, but i don't have a clue on finally showing the tree.

What am i missing? Any one help me? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Ivan Bozhanov, the jsTree plug in creator, answered me quickly at the jsTree google forums...
Here is my working code:

```
$('#showTree').jstree({
'core' : {
   'data' : {
            'url': 'miley.json',
             'data' : function (node) {
                                      return { 'id' : node.id };
                                      }
        }
          }
});
```

Also, i made some changes to miley, and deleted the last comma in the first miley.json I posted above...:

```
[
   { "id" : "ajson1", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Simple root node" },
   { "id" : "ajson2", "parent" : "ajson1", "text" : "Root node 2" },
   { "id" : "ajson3", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Child 1" },
   { "id" : "ajson4", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Child 2" }
]
```